# The score resets when scene resets

Tags: python, game-engine

I need help keeping score when I reset the scene.

This is the game file link.  https://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/92672

My score shouldn't reset when resetting scene.  It should stay when scene resets.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a Game actuator, load global dict and save global dict, i dont know how this actuator works. i think you'll need little bit of python to do this.
google for "bge global-dict". there are a few tutorials on youtube.
or you can just create a file. 
with open("file", "w") as f: f.write() f.close(), 
save the file a openit up from other scene. 
with open("file", "r") as f: f.readLine() f.read()... and so.
It's basically the same thing. A dict that blender handles or a "dict" you handle.

Comment: This doesn't help me.

Comment: If the right answer does'nt help you. You must be some special kind of common factor. Good luck!

Comment: I want the game to do it all itself

Comment: I see, so ask to your game how to do it.

Comment: the game should do just what you said above